# pandas delete column value from other 2 columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe

```
team          team2     condition   Required_Col
Australia   Sri Lanka   Sri Lanka   Australia
Australia   Sri Lanka   Sri Lanka   Australia
Australia   Sri Lanka   Sri Lanka   Australia
Australia   Sri Lanka   Australia   Sri Lanka
Australia   Sri Lanka   Australia   Sri Lanka
```

I want to create the `Required_Col` such that if the value is in `condition` column then the value other than `condition` in `team` and `team2` column should be selected. What's the best way to do this in pandas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using **`np.where`**

```
df['required'] = np.where(df.condition == df.team, df.team2, df.team)

        team     team2  condition   required
0  Australia  SriLanka   SriLanka  Australia
1  Australia  SriLanka   SriLanka  Australia
2  Australia  SriLanka   SriLanka  Australia
3  Australia  SriLanka  Australia   SriLanka
4  Australia  SriLanka  Australia   SriLanka
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.apply()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df['Required_Col'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['team2'] if (x['condition']==x['team']) else x['team'], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
        team    team2       condition   Required_Col
0   Australia   SriLanka    SriLanka    Australia
1   Australia   SriLanka    SriLanka    Australia
2   Australia   SriLanka    SriLanka    Australia
3   Australia   SriLanka    Australia   SriLanka
4   Australia   SriLanka    Australia   SriLanka
```